# How to inject framework into custom class?

Tags: php, rest, registry, flightphp

I'm currently developing an application with the FlightPHP framework and wondering how am I able to inject FlightPHP into my custom class so that I am able to use specific classes I have injected into it's dependency container.

```
use Flight;
use Logger;

class DB{

    public function __construct(...){

        $this->app = $app; // Flight:: instance

    }

    public function doStuff($stuff){

        return $this->app->log()->function($stuff);

    }

}

Flight::register('log', 'Logger', ['app'], function($log) {
    return $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('app.log'));
});

Flight::register('database', 'DB', array($data), function($db) {
    return $db;
});
```

I'm attempting to inject Flight into my database class constructor so that I am able to use the log function which was previously injected into the Flight dependency container.

The "Logger" works in the index.php when used under the Flight instance "`Flight::log()->function("test");`", however when I attempt to use it in another scope(within the Database class), it doesn't allow me to use it in the context of "Flight".

Update:

```
Flight::register('log', 'Monolog\Logger', ['app'], function($log) {
    return $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('app.log'));
});

class DB{
    function __construct(Monolog\Logger $engine){

        #var_dump($engine);
        $engine->addInfo("injected"); // works

    }
}

Flight::register('database', 'DB', array(Flight::log()), function($db) {
    return $db;
});
Flight::database();
```

Is correct usage?

Comment: So you are saying that you are not able to receive/inject instance of Flight in DB constructor? What hides under those ... ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass Flight into the DB constructor so that my custom class(DB) is able to utilize other classes I have injected into the Flight dependency container.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass instance of `\Flight\Engine` in the array of third parameter at `register` method to pass framework instance in you DB controller. `\Flight\Engine` does not use interface sou you are coupling your code with framework implementation I guess. In this case you can use `Flight::app()` everywhere to obtain framework instance.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


class DB
{
    function __construct(\Flight\Engine $engine)
    {
        var_dump($engine->get('connectionString'));
    }
}

Flight::set('connectionString', 'mssql');
Flight::register('database', 'DB', array(Flight::app()), function($db) {
    return $db;
});

Flight::database();
```

Looks like that Flight does not have such a concept as Dependency Injection Container. You have to specify your parameter values explicitly.

Update:

By doing this `['app']` you are injecting string into constructor of `Monolog\Logger`. This line `return $log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('app.log'));` should raise error.

Read more carefully http://flightphp.com/learn

Comment: I guess this is on the right tracks I'm attempting to achieve, adjusted this a little and kind of works however not sure if I'm doing it correctly in the constructor and the register array, have added my version to the main post.

Comment: I updated my answer. Looks okay, but does Logger really need this string 'app' ?

Comment: Yes Logger requires one argument in it's constructor which is the name of the current logging profile.